# Illustrator technical drawings format from Indesign

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

I'm designing a big products catalog with lot of technical drawings, every product has at least one drawings made in illustrator and linked (from an assets server). In the catalog, often dimensional quotes are too small, sometimes unreadable, cause the images will be printed so small.

Is there a way to resize only dimensional quotes' font size from indesign without resizing the entire drawing or reopening every original file in illustrator?

Maybe is a wrong workflow? I know that the technical drawings should be made in a better readable way, expecially in small size, but it is the work of years.

Thank you

Comment: You mean the dimensions are written as text inside the Illustrator files themselves? I don’t think there’s any way to edit that from InDesign; unlike Affinity products, the Adobe suite programs are completely separate. Is there other writing in the Illustrator files as well? If there is, manually adjusting each drawing is probably the only option. Resize the artwork to the final print size (as placed in InDesign), then set the font size to the desired point size; rinse and repeat for every drawing.

Comment: If the dimensions are the _only_ text in the AI files, you _may_ be able to script your way around the issue. **In InDesign:** Make sure you have all the drawings placed at their final print sizes, iterate through them and store the file name and print size of each drawing in a text file. **In Illustrator:** Iterate over the text file, open each file in it, resize artwork to the print size, change point size of all text objects to the desired output size. If the dimensions are near any lines, though, the type may overlap and block out part of the actual drawing itself.

Comment: The dimensions are the only text.
There is no way of editing them manually, they are above 10 thousands of technical drawings. I will reflect on scripting but yes, the dimensions are near lines so I think that they will overlap. Ty

Comment: I agree that this *might* be possible to script, but that would probably take several hours and require access to the InDesign document and the drawings to analyze what they have in common. Not something one could easily explain in an answer here, and more about coding than graphic design. As you mention, the hardest part will probably be to make sure the texts won't overlap the lines. Whether it's possible to avoid depends a lot on how exactly the files are made and if it's possible to apply some logic to scale the texts away from the lines.

Comment: To be honest this is not a solvable problem. The original person who made tha drawing had to fit the vales into the drawing. With 10 000 drawings your unlikely to solve this easily.

Comment: The only real solution is to ensure the font size in *all* linked assets is set the same and large enough to be read once placed into InDesign. And then scale all assets the same amount within InDesign. I do this often with chart labels.. ensure everything is the same size in the AI document so when placed and reduced, it all scales the same.

Comment: @Scott That would be ideal, but it only works if the drawings themselves have the same scale and are to be reproduced at the same scale, which may not be the case.

Comment: I will often remove labels from AI files and recreate those labels in InDesign so type can be more uniform.